# updating rails previous project to current version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have a project of rails with versions ruby 1.8.7, gems 1.3.6, rails 2.3.5

I want to update the project to the current version can you guys please give the picture how to update older rails applications to current version....
thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM and Bundler with the use of a gemfile is helpful in the situation you are in.

---

**RUBY Versioning**

1. Install Ruby Version Manager (pay careful instructions to how to install)
   Installation documentation for RVM is here https://rvm.io/rvm/install/
2. once installed download the version of RUBY you want to use
   rvm install 1.9.3 or **rvm install 1.8.7**
3. afterwards type in **RVM use 1.8.7** and it will set your system to use the older version

---

**Gem Versioning**

- Apparently you can install the gems in rails 2 by using the rake command

  enter in **rake gems:install**
- Your code to config gems are located in the config/environment.rb
  There is a helpful tool called "Bundler" which is a gem that easily lets you manage your gem version through the use of a file called a "gemfile". I think the link below is a good resource on how to upgrade your Rails 2 project
  http://llamarada-cinetica.heroku.com/blog/2011/02/14/using-gemfiles-on-rails

with RVM and gem configuration you can upgrade gems as needed and check if it works with your build.
(others please correct me if i'm wrong I've only been on rails for a short while)

Comment: its odd type in "blog/2011/02/14/using-gemfiles-on-rails-2-x-apps" in google and it'll lead you to the promise land.

Comment: thank you i will test and i will come back to you thank you for your consideration...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is If your client want you to update the project you can update else extend the application features with older version of Rails because lots of features will break if you upgrade to new Rails version.

And your question is not suitable to ask in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this question now unsuitable for stackoverflow?

Comment: i am new to to rails i previously worked on java, but due to the requirement i jumped to rails i did not have an opportunity to explore more about rails, i asked a good way to deploy my application or an existing application on the given environment not the suggestion of do according to the client. client is quiet comfortable with any of the ways.....as if i am working on rails installer while developing a new app i did not got any problem so customizing the environment is some what hard thing which i required to be guided....thank you....